# Solr 6.1 - Get all token counts for a Facet field across all documents

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a TextField in my solr schema.xml on which I want to run faceting and find out counts for every tokens in that field across all the documents. Is there a way to get this? I tried following and I thought it was working until I found out that it's not a complete list of tokens that I am getting form this query:
`http://solrnode1:8983/solr/mycollection/select?facet.field=PRODUCT_NAME&facet=on&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&rows=0`

For example, there is one document in that field that says "Education Services 2014" but I don't see any facet token for 'education' with its count. Interestingly if I change my query parameter to `q=PRODUCT_NAME:*education*` instead of `q=*:*` then it shows up in faceting with count! I am not sure what's happening here. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a `facet.limit` which is by default 100. I increased it and its getting more tokens and counts now.